# Modal not spawned properly centered when scrolled. Not spawned in the middle of the viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

The problem is that the Modal always pops up in the middle of the "total" page. [See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsBs2.png) .

I am using a Bootstrap Carousel that when you click on the active image.jpg it shows the image-fullsize.jpg using a Bootstrap Modal. The image shown in either the Carousel and the Modal are working perfectly, the problem is the spawn position of the Modal. It looks like if its always spawned in the same (x,y) position, no matter where you are on the page.

I will like to continue using this Carousel-Modal approach but maybe it is not the best method. I will listen to any solution!

**Here is the Carousel Code:**

```
<div id="carouselID" class="carousel slide"  data-interval="false">
    <div class="carousel-inner" style="cursor: pointer;" role="listbox"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
        <img src="image.jpg">
        <img src="image2.jpg">
        <img src="image3.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

**Here is the Modal Code:**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-full modal-xl" role="document"> //FullScreen-ish Modal
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">ASDFASDF</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <img id="carousel_clicked_img"> //I use Jquery to show the correct fullsize-image.jpg
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have already tried adding `modal-dialog-centered` along with `modal-dialog` and tried:

```
 .modal-dialog {
    position: absolute; //If I use fixed the Modal always spawns at the bottom of the page
    top: 50%; //If i use 80% it gives me a scrolleable-ish semi-broken modal that spawns below desired position
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) !important;
}
```

and I tried hundreds of recommended solutions and got nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Change `position` property to `fixed`

```
.modal-dialog {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%; //If i use 80% it gives me a scrolleable-ish semi-broken modal that spans below desired position
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) !important;
}
```

Comment: I have already tried it. Using this approach always spawn the Modal at the bottom of the page

Comment: what if you add `margin: 0!important` to `.modal-dialog` ?

Comment: it changes nothing :C

Comment: Can you provide a link to website or make a screenshot with open  dev tools with  .modal-dialog details?

Comment: OMG I LOVE YOU! I had no .modal-dialog css.. But thanks to you I opened Dev Tools (I'm kinda newbie) and I discover that when Modal opens it calls a `.modal-open{overflow: hidden}`so I changed to `overflow: auto !important` and now is working with a scrolleable Modal!!!! Thank you very much!